# CodePush update does not work with react native iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, code-push

I'm trying to configure CodePush on my iOS app developed by ReactNative, following these links :

https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/docs/getting-started.html

https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/docs/cli.html

Every single step is configured properly and double checked, but when I trace the process with chrome debugger,
the output will be like this :

```
 [CodePush] Checking for update.                              CodePush.js:159
 [CodePush] An unknown error occured                          CodePush.js:159
 [CodePush] 404: The specified resource does not exist.       CodePush.js:159
```

Any solution?

Comment: I know you wrote you double checked your configuration, but it looks a lot like a missing or wrong deployment key. Can you re-check that your CodePushDeploymentKey value is set correctly in your info.plist. If you have multiple Info.plist files for different builds make sure they all contain CodePushDeploymentKey

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me as well because I was using app secret as a deployment key.

App secret and a deployment key are different.

deployment key you can get by the following command

```
appcenter codepush deployment list --app Owner/Appname -k
```

│ Name       │ Key                                   │
├────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Production │ I6rJbnQdfdfdfdfdDgjJ0zqrAn6rNE7Q0JTF │
├────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Staging    │ kbwhyeLlEhR4XRxXjFOi_h5lBNXuiRtdffdf │
└────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┘

`appcenter codepush release-react -a Owner/Appname -d Production or Staging`

whatever key you have used

Answer (score -1):

you should release a version to code-push server. Then you code-push client can be check the update states.

Comment: You don't have to deploy an initial version. If no bundle is deployed you will receive a SyncStatus.UP_TO_DATE

Comment: I am use 1.10.0-beta. The first time I tested, it tell me 404: The specified resource does not exist. After I am upload a bundle. The code-push sync work.

Comment: Are you sure you created the deployment before testing? The update check basically sends a HTTP GET with the deployment key and app version to an endpoint maintained by Microsoft. When the deployment key exists, even if there has never been anything pushed to it, you get a 200 response indicating that no update is available. If the deployment key does not exist, a 404 is returned.

Comment: ok,Maybe I am not create deployment before test. I am sorry for that.